# Can you Schedule a Gitlab Runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to schedule the uptime on a runner?
We have a machine that is used heavily for other non-gitlab jobs during the day, so would only like it only accept jobs overnight, as we used to have on jenkins. Is this possible? If so - how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use gitlab api to activate or disable runners. see the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#update-runners-details)

For example:

```
PUT /runners/:id 

active: false
```